# Select SQL statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

A table has six records `1,2,3,4,5,6`. I need only 3 rows, so I use `order desc limit 3` and I got values like this `4,5,6`. But what I need is `4,5`only. Is there any method for this?

Answer (score 1):

A nested select could work:

```
select * from (
  select * from table_with_six_records order by id desc limit 3
) as t1 limit 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
order desc limit 3,2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following
select * from TABLE order by id desc limit 3, 2